# Ext4 How to reconfigure the component "ftype:search"

Tags: extjs

First i create a gird panel with {store:store1, column:column1} ;

I add `ftype: 'search'` component to grid panel,

then i use `grid.reconfigure(store2,column2)` to change the store and column.

after that ,  i found when i click the `search`  button , ext use the store1 to request,

so my question is how to reconfigure the search component like the `xtype: 'pagingtoolbar'`'s method `bindStore(store2)`?

Answer (score 1):

you should do that afterrender the view in controller 
I added a button in my code here in pagingtoolbar
I have gridpanel called customerShippingAddressesFormGrid 
so I add new button to it's pagingtoolbar 
and I added a listener when i click on it to add new row to my gridpanel

```
 customerShippingAddressesFormGrid.pagingToolbar.add(
        new Ext.button.Button(
        {
           xtype: 'button',
           itemId: 'addButton',
           icon: 'Images/Lists_New.png',
           text: this.addButtonText,
           tooltip: this.addNewText,
           scope: this,
           listeners:
           {
              click: function ()
              {
                 if (customerIDFormList.comboBox.getValue())
                 {
                    var customerShippingAddressStore = customerShippingAddressesFormGrid.getStore();
                    customerShippingAddressStore.add({});
                 }
              }
           }
        }));
```